# Flip x y positions

Tags: javascript

For my game, my server *objects API* is serving all the informations for **game objects/items** as JSON.

My objects has directions. Direction system works with **flipping**: If you flip Direction `6`, you obtain direction `0`. Each object has **layers**. Each **layer** has an *image* and its *predefined* `x, y` (`top, left` in px) position so the **object** can be assembled.

So I want to send to the client objects that are alerdy flipped. If I have direction `6`, and the client request is direction `0`, my server will flip each layer *images* and `x,y` *coordinates* **of the direction** **6** so the object can be correctly assembled **WITH FLIPPED** images and the client doesn't have *to flip anything*, just to assemble the object with the given `x,y` coordinates for each layer.

Flipping images is okay, I did it and I don't have any problems. But I don't know what should I do to make the X,Y coordinates working with the flipped layers images and so it's not drawing correctly.

**Example**:
Unflipped layer info:

```
direction: 6,
base64ImageURL: [b64 string],
x: 42,
y: 16
```

Flipped layer info should be:

```
direction: 0,
base64ImageURL: [b64 string flipped],
x: ??,
y: ??
```

**Another example:**

For example, I have **3** layers on my object: layer `1`, `2` and `3`
Direction `0` is the result of *flipping* direction `6`.
So I have this in direction 6:

```
{
    Layer1: {image: "[b64 image]", x:32, y:20},
    Layer2: {image: "[b64 image]", x:50, y:45},
    Layer3: {image: "[b64 image]", x:10, y:65}
}
```

So when I flip each layer image to have a Direction 0 info object, the x,y positions should also be changed, otherwise layers are not correctly assembled. But what should I do to the `x & y`? Which operation?

Comment: You essentially want to [transpose the images pixels](http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-rotate-image-using-javascript-canvas.html)?

Comment: I want to flip the images and its drawing coords. I did it with `scale(-1, 1);` so now I need to flip the x, y positions and I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly get if you want to flip or transpose the image. The `.scale(-1,1)` should flip the image over its Y axis.

Just add this css to your image class:

```
.flipped {
    transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -khtml-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
```

Or going by your code, I have a hunch that this might work:

```
context.scale(-1, 1);
context.drawImage(image, image.width, 0);
```

Removing the `-` sign from `image.width`

Comment: The problem is not concerning the image, it's about x and y coordinates of layers when the image is flipped

Comment: For example, I have 3 layers on my object: layer1, 2 and 3
Direction 0 is the result of flipping direction 6.
So I have this in direction 6:
`Layer1: x=32; y=20;
Layer2: x=50; y=45;
Layer3: x=10; y=65;`

So when I flip each layer image, the x,y positions should also be changed, otherwise layers are not correctly assembled. But what should I do to the x & y? Which operation?

Comment: What do these `x,y` co-ordinates represent? Top-left corner of the layer? Do all the layers have equal size?

Comment: Top & left position in pixel. No, layers have differents sizes